pthread_cond_timedwait blocks with SCHED_FIFO and rtprio set to 99
I'm investigating a problem where pthread_cond_timedwait() appears to block even though the absolute wait time has clearly passed.
The program I'm investigating has all of its threads set to use SCHED_FIFO. And the problem only exists when I add this line *  -  rtprio  99 to /etc/security/limits.conf.
I tried constructing a minimum reproducible program, but pthread_cond_timedwait() worked expectedly in the test program.
Furthermore, when the problem happens attaching gdb to the program would hang forever. I added a pair of printf() around pthread_cond_timedwait(), and the message of the second printf() never showed up.
I'm fairly new to Linux, does anyone have any idea why pthread_cond_timedwait() would block past wait time?

pthread_cond_timedwait() must re-acquire the mutex before returning if there was a timeout, so potentially another thread is holding the mutex.
Alternatively, using a realtime scheduling class means that your thread can be prevented from running by other realtime threads in the same priority class failing to block or yield in a timely manner. This is what it means to use realtime scheduling: you gain predictability but the cost is that you must take on the burden of scheduling.
